# How to create a Hashcash in PHP

Tags: php

After searching the Web, I couldn't find an answer on how to create a hashcode in php.

I'm writing a Newsletter-Tool and don't wan't to get blacklisted, ok who wants :-)

I have already checked my reverse DNS, SPF an spamhouse.org...

Can someone help me out on how to create a hashcash in PHP (with example)?

Comment: As long as your emails don't seem overly spammy and you've taken the proper DNS steps, you shouldn't have to worry about it.  (Though this isn't really helpful towards the question...)

Comment: are you implementing hascash in `wordpress`?

Comment: There's source code for various languages available at the official site, shouldn't be too hard to translate one of those to PHP: http://hashcash.org/libs/

Comment: I implemented [Hashcash](https://github.com/TheFox/hashcash) into PHP. It's also available via [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/thefox/hashcash).

Answer (score 1):

TheFox has implemented Hashcash into PHP which is available on [Github](https://github.com/TheFox/hashcash)

#### Installation

> The preferred method of installation is via [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/thefox/hashcash) and [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Run the following command to install the package and add it as a requirement to composer.json:

```
composer.phar require "thefox/hashcash=~1.0"
```

#### Example

An example usage of that implementation is:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use TheFox\Pow\Hashcash;
$hashcash = new Hashcash(20, 'example@example.com');
print "hashcash stamp: '".$hashcash->mint()."'\n";
?>
```

---

Also, the hashcash.org website has developer notes on how to [implement it yourself](http://hashcash.org/dev/) as well as [OS specific tools](http://hashcash.org/tool/) available which can be used via `shell_exec()` in PHP