# HashCash - PHP & JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Hashcash in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135914/how-to-create-a-hashcash-in-php)

I suppose my first question would be, is "hashcash" any use in improving security (especially given Moore's Law)?

If so, my second question is, does anyone know how to implement it in PHP & JavaScript? The website for it (http://hashcash.org/) is old and has a dead link for a JavaScript and PHP implementation, and **I can't find basically anything about it**, specifically how to make and use it with these two languages.

Any help would be welcome. :-)

Comment: If you can't find anything about, that should answer your question as to how useful it turned out to be...

Comment: I suppose... I still wouldn't mind messing with it though. :o

Comment: How would you use it to improve security?

Comment: There's a [Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/hashcash) plugin for whatever this is. And it's recently maintained. You know that Drupal is a PHP and Javascript-based site management program? And there's a more recent Wordpress plugin too. There still seems to be plenty of stuff out there, in other words.

Comment: @Gumbo - It's apparently used to model non-finite problems that real humans and unreal chimps would have to solve. Did you know raccoons have *hands*? Human-like hands? Maybe they could figure it out too.